# XLS files not getting exported by using apache.poi and jaspereport showing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$WHITE

Tags: java, apache-poi, jasper-reports, wildfly

I’m using jasper report v. 6.17.0 to generate reports and apache poi - 4.1.2 , poi-ooxml- 4.1.2, ooxml-schemas- 1.4 and poi-ooxml-schemas- 4.1.2
In order to exports the generated reports in pdf, docs, xls and xlsx format.
Only the xls format is not working

the code is mentioned below

```
        JRAbstractExporter  exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Here we assign the parameters jp and baos to the exporter
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
        if(ReportOutputType.XLS.equals(reportOutputType) || ReportOutputType.XLSX.equals(reportOutputType)){
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
            exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
           
            
        }

        try {
            exporter.exportReport();

        } catch (JRException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return baos;
```

Here as soon as the instance of JRXLSexporter() is executed then I get the exception as -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/hssf/util/HSSFColor$WHITE
    at deployment.dp.war//net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.<init>(JRXlsExporter.java:163)
    at deployment.dp.war//net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.<init>(JRXlsExporter.java:191)
    at deployment.dp.war//com.apc.dp.view.utils.exports.ReportsExporter.getReportOutputType(ReportsExporter.java:56)
    at deployment.dp.war//com.apc.dp.view.utils.exports.ReportsExporter.<init>(ReportsExporter.java:74)
    at deployment.dp.war//com.apc.dp.controller.solution.SolutionReportsController.getPartNumberReports(SolutionReportsController.java:963)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at deployment.dp.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor$WHITE from [Module "deployment.dp.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 72 more
```

I followed the articles where they advice to keep the jar files in the classpath but none of them worked.
I tried updating the poi jars to latest version that also didn’t help.Please see my entirepom.xml and suggest accordingly.
pom.xml link - https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/sisa9236nb5m4dx75gtc2/pom.paper?dl=0&rlkey=hr73iolribgw3e5xvu6a08y4s

Comment: What version of Apache POI does your chosen version of Jasper Report require? And what happens when you get the version that Jasper expects and the one you supply to correctly match?

Comment: You can find the right version of library at [pom.xml](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/6.17.0/jasperreports/pom.xml)

Comment: @AlexK  How to get the exact version, I didnt get it.. could you please help.

Comment: @Gagravarr , I've many other POI reports which are working fine with this POI and jasper-reports version. Only I'm facing issue with one particular report while exporting to excel